# title toggle disappears on click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, toggle

Trying to make a toggle work that open/closes content. Opening the content works but somehow the button with the title disappears. Why?

```
<script>
const show = ref(false);
</script>

<template>
  <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 mx-auto my-12 border-8 border-black">
    <button v-if="!show" class="bg-blue-500" @click="show = true">
      <h2>Hello title, click to open or close content</h2>
    </button>
    <div v-show="show" class="bg-red-500">
      <p>The content becomes available when you click to open, and is hidden when clicked again to close.
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Why the title disappears and how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title disappears when you click it because the `v-if` expression, `!show`, evaluates to `false` and thus the element would be removed from the DOM. Consider removing the `v-if` attribute from the `<button>` element if you would like it to always be displayed.

Comment: but then the content does not close anymore, cannot toggle.

Comment: The content would not close originally, with or without the `v-if` attribute. If you want the content to be togglable, consider changing the `@click` value to be `@click="show = !show"`.